# Read a file from the cache in CEFSharp

Tags: pdf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I need to navigate to a web site that ultimately contains a .pdf file and I want to save that file locally.  I am using CEFSharp to do this.  The nature of this site is such that once the .pdf appears in the browser, it cannot be accessed again.  For this reason, I was wondering if once you have a .pdf displayed in the browser, is there a way to access the source for that file in the cache?

I have tried implementing IDownloadHandler and that works, but you have to click the save button on the embedded .pdf.  I am trying to get around that.

Comment: `CEF` does not provide a means of accessing the `cache` (you could probably read the `db` directly, though I've never tried). You can implement a `ResourceHandler` and download the file yourself, caching it locally. The implementation of a `ResourceHandler` is slightly different based on which branch your using. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/49/CefSharp.Example/FlashResourceHandler.cs#L22 should be a starting point, just switch branches to see the different version if your using an older version.

Comment: I have tried this approach in my earlier version of this project that used the .Net WebBrowser.  The problem I ran into was that the created HTMLRequest didn't have the cookies or whatever security information in order to access the .pdf.  Is there a way to pass the security information cached in the browser to the HTMLRequest?

Comment: I guess you could query the cookie store though that's getting more complex. There is another option though very new and not particularly well tested. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/1519

Comment: I think that is the ticket.  I can implement what is basically a Pass Through Response Filter that checks for a PDF header and saves it locally before sending the stream on its way.  Is there a way to wire this up without implementing the entire IRequestHandler?

Comment: I implemented the Pass Through Response Filter.  At a certain point on a page, the dataIn.Length will exceed the dataOut.Length.  I tried fixing this by

                dataIn.CopyTo(dataOut, (int)dataOutWritten);

I still get 
System.NotSupportedException: Unable to expand length of this stream beyond its capacity.

Comment: What does your code look like? If you use the sample code provided are you seeing the same problem?

Comment: Yes. I used the exact code from here as proof of concept before doing anything to save the stream.  https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/Filters/PassThruResponseFilter.cs  It works fine for a bit then you get a condition where dataOut.Length is like 4K and dataIn.Length is 32K.  It gives the above error.  I got what I needed to work by only applying my filter when the url is to a .pdf.  I will post my solution after I make sure it works a day or two.  The site I am polling runs on the Siebel engine.  It is private so I can't send a link.

Comment: That is unexpected, though the scenaio is supported. If you look at the other `IResponseFilter` examples they're more detailed. You basically write what you can do the buffer, store the overflow and ask for more data. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/49/CefSharp.Example/Filters/AppendResponseFilter.cs#L81

Comment: Definitely unexpected.  You would think that the dataOut.Length would always be 32K.  In any case I tried what you said and it would get past the error, but the page didn't work right once it loaded.  The default filter, whatever it is, seems to handle it fine, so only loading my filter when its a .pdf is what I am going with.  I know we are not supposed to thank people on Stack Exchange, but CEFSharp and your support of it have made my project possible.  Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, here is how I got it to work.  There is a function in CEFSharp that allows you to filter an incoming web response.  Consequently, this gives you complete access to the incoming stream.  My solution is a little on the dirty side and not particularly efficient, but it works for my situation.  If anyone sees a better way, I am open for suggestions.  There are two things I have to assume in order for my code to work.

1. GetResourceResponseFilter is called every time a new page is downloaded.
2. The PDF is that last thing to be downloaded during the navigation process.

Start with the CEF Minimal Example found here : https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

I used the WinForms version.  Implement the IRequestHandler and IResponseFilter in the form definition as follows:

```
public partial class BrowserForm : Form, IRequestHandler, IResponseFilter
{
    public readonly ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

    public BrowserForm(string url)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url)
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        };

        toolStripContainer.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.BrowserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
        browser.BrowserSettings.UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
        browser.BrowserSettings.WebSecurity = CefState.Disabled;
        browser.BrowserSettings.Javascript = CefState.Enabled;

        browser.LoadingStateChanged += OnLoadingStateChanged;
        browser.ConsoleMessage += OnBrowserConsoleMessage;
        browser.StatusMessage += OnBrowserStatusMessage;
        browser.TitleChanged += OnBrowserTitleChanged;
        browser.AddressChanged += OnBrowserAddressChanged;
        browser.FrameLoadEnd += browser_FrameLoadEnd;

        browser.LifeSpanHandler = this;
        browser.RequestHandler = this;
```

The declaration and the last two lines are the most important for this explanation.  I implemented the IRequestHandler using the template found here:
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/RequestHandler.cs
I changed everything to what it recommends as default except for GetResourceResponseFilter which I implemented as follows:

```
    IResponseFilter IRequestHandler.GetResourceResponseFilter(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
    {
        if (request.Url.EndsWith(".pdf"))
            return this;

        return null;
    }
```

I then implemented IResponseFilter as follows:

```
    FilterStatus IResponseFilter.Filter(Stream dataIn, out long dataInRead, Stream dataOut, out long dataOutWritten)
    {

        BinaryWriter sw;

        if (dataIn == null)
        {
            dataInRead = 0;
            dataOutWritten = 0;

            return FilterStatus.Done;
        }

        dataInRead = dataIn.Length;
        dataOutWritten = Math.Min(dataInRead, dataOut.Length);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[dataOutWritten];
        int bytesRead = dataIn.Read(buffer, 0, (int)dataOutWritten);

        string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        if (s.StartsWith("%PDF"))
            File.Delete(pdfFileName);
        sw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(pdfFileName, FileMode.Append));
        sw.Write(buffer);
        sw.Close();

        dataOut.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        return FilterStatus.Done;
    }

    bool IResponseFilter.InitFilter()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

What I found is that the PDF is actually downloaded twice when it is loaded.  In any case, there might be header information and what not at the beginning of the page.  When I get a stream segment that begins with %PDF, I know it is the beginning of a PDF so I delete the file to discard any previous contents that might be there.  Otherwise, I just keep appending each segment to the end of the file.  Theoretically, the PDF file will be safe until you navigate to another PDF, but my recommendation is to do something with the file as soon as the page is loaded just to be safe.

Comment: Perfect Solution